# PHP email doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to figure out how to build a contact form, but I can't understand where is the error.
This is my html form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php"> <!-- contact form -->
   <h4>Inviaci un Messaggio</h4>
   <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
     <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Nome (richiesto)" />
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
     <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email (richiesto)" />
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
     <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Oggetto" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Testo (richiesto)"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" class="btn" />
  </form>
```

and this is mail.php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
mail("my@mail.com", $subject,
$message, "From:" . $email);
?>
```

where am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What error it displays when you try to send the mail (if any)?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an error? A blank screen? Sends the wrong email?

Comment: just try to print the values that you are getting after posting the form, see if data is coming in it or the post is blank

Comment: that mail function requires you to configure php.ini for the runtime to know where your stmp server is. more at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: are you trying to run the code locally?

Comment: No error .. just when I send the email .. nothing comes.. No, i'm on server

Comment: Don't forget to check your Spam folder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending mail from PHP is fraught with difficulties. You might not have an error in your code, but the mail might not be delivered because (select as many as you wish):

- it doesn't appear to come from an email address on the server;
- outbound email is blocked by default until you ask for it;
- your server is blacklisted;
- your message is blocked by a spam filter;
- some other reason.

Make life easy on yourself. Use a library like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/%E2%80%8E) to handle sending the mail, and try something easy like delivering to an address on the sending server. Then work up from there. Be prepared to have to use SMTP Authentication, and possibly a paid external service to send the mail for you.

Comment: +1. All good advice, especially using a decent mailer library. I don't understand why so many people put so much effort into trying to make PHP's built-in `mail()` function work.